# Python Check txt variable loop

Tags: python, loops, variables

I need function to check in name.txt variable if variable will changed print 1 and again if variable 2 times change again print 1. Its possible to do in python?http://pastebin.com/Qa0ed3nM

fr = open("plik.txt",'r')
first_length = len(str(fr.read()))
while True:
    text = str(fr.read())
    if(len(text)!=first_length):
        fr.close()
        fw = open("plik.txt","w")
        fw.write(text)
        fw.close()
        print("done")
        break;

Comment: Almost anything is possible in Python.  But if you ask questions like this without doing any research first, people aren't going to respond well.  Try not to treat this like a human-powered Google, and save questions for when you're stuck with an actual problem.

Comment: You need to have trued..

Comment: Hi Kuncioso. Like Chris says almost anything is possible in Python and I'm sure people will be able to help you out but it might be useful if we could see the contents of name.txt and maybe some code you've tried (people here generally, and myself included, just really like looking at code when helping people with a question!) :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this function can help:

```
def checkChange(FileName, oldContent):
    fSrc = open(FileName, 'r')
    actualContent = fSrc.read()
    fSrc.close()
    if actualContent != oldContent:
        print(1)
    return actualContent
```